# getElementByID returning null?

Tags: javascript, element

I am having trouble getting my elements by ID, as they keep returning null.

I've noticed some people have this problem with the script loading before the DOM but I'm not sure how to fix this issue from an external js script.

I've tried a few different variations but would like to keep my js scipts external if possible. I've also tried changing the listener, element, id, etc.

Any and all help is appreciated. I know this question has been asked a couple of times but I couldn't find an answer in terms I understand, but please direct me to threads of this caliber if they exist. Thank you!

> Note: I am currently learning js, having known HTML and CSS. Not sure if this is something jquery could take care of.

```js
let computerSelection;
let playerSelection;
let rockbtn = document.getElementById("button");


function computerPlay() {
  computerSelection = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  switch (computerSelection) {
    case 0:
      computerSelection = "ROCK";
      break;
    case 1:
      computerSelection = "PAPER";
      break;
    default:
      computerSelection = "SCISSORS"
  }
  return computerSelection;
}





function playGame(computerSelection, playerSelection) {
  playerSelection = chooseForMe();
  computerSelection = computerPlay();
  console.log(`You threw ${playerSelection} and computer threw ${computerSelection}`);
  if (computerSelection === playerSelection) {
    console.log("Tie Game. Go Again");
  }

  if (playerSelection === "ROCK" && computerSelection === "SCISSORS") {
    console.log("You win!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "ROCK" && computerSelection === "PAPER") {
    console.log("You lose!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "PAPER" && computerSelection === "ROCK") {
    console.log("You win!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "PAPER" && computerSelection === "SCISSORS") {
    console.log("You lose!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "SCISSORS" && computerSelection === "PAPER") {
    console.log("You win!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "SCISSORS" && computerSelection === "ROCK") {
    console.log("You lose!");
  }
}

rockbtn.addEventListener("click", playGame);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Smokum&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="java.js"></script>
  <title>Java Page</title>
</head>
<header>
  <div class="container" <p id="header">Rock Paper Scissors?</p>
  </div>
</header>

<body>
  <button id="button">Rock</button>
  <button id="paperbutton">Paper</button>
  <button id="scissorsbutton">Scissors</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding your JS _after_ your `<body>` element? And by that I mean move `<script src="java.js"></script>` (why `java?`) after the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: If the script you've included is what's in java.js (java?), it's running before the DOM has loaded, thus those elements don't exist yet.

Comment: you can wait for the dom to be loaded before executing your script https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: @TimLewis fair enough, should probably change the name of the js file. And thank you, that's the one thing I hadn't tried.

Comment: No problem! And there's nothing wrong with calling a file `java.js`, it's mostly just humorous  Many beginner programmers incorrectly think that `java` and `javascript` are the same thing (or at the very least related), but they are quite different. Cheers, and happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

check if your script tag is above the element that you want to get or below.